# Add domain as CNAME in Azure

Tags: azure, cname

I try to achieve something like this.

My App runs on xyz.azurewebsites.net .
Now I want that the CNAME 123.azurewebsites.net redirects to xyz.azurewebsites.net

123.azurewebsites.net --> xyz.azurewebsites.net

I tried to add that CNAME in the Azure portal under custom domains put everytime I click "Add Custom Domain" I get the alert Message "Your unsaved edits will be discarded." And when I click "Ok" nothing happen.

In my notifications I get the message "Failed to add hostname 123.azurewebsites.net. 123.azurewebsites.net is invalid."

Is this a problem because I try to redirect from one "azurewebsites" domain to another "azurewebsites" domain or do I miss out something?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom domain sometimes takes a long time to update. Check back in 20 minutes to see if the change has gone through. If you go to [www.digwebinterface.com](https://www.digwebinterface.com) and type your custom domain name in, "xyz.azurewebsites.net" you should see that it has mapped it to your original host name, "123.azurewebsites.net".

Comment: well in my notifications it said "Failed to add hostname <myname>.azurewebsites.net. <myname>.azurewebsites.net is invalid." so I don't think it even went through

Comment: I think you have to create a CNAME record first. You can do this by adding a DNS zone if you don't have an external DNS provider. You then create a CNAME record in the DNS zone. If you have a look here then it explains it in more detail. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-a-cname-record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-a-cname-record)

Comment: Also look at this for configuring the DNS Zone with the domain: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain#app-service-web-apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain#app-service-web-apps)